# COUNTIFS where it doesn't show zero for future months

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a workbook that contains 3 worksheets.  On the summary sheet I want to obtain the monthly totals as each month occurs.  I don't want it to show anything for those months that haven't occurred yet.  For example, I don't want anything showing in cell for July 2023's total until next month.  This is the formula that I have so far: =COUNTIFS(CC[Date of Case Closure],">=7/1/23",CC[Date of Case Closure],"<=7/31/23")

Right now it is showing 0 as the total.  I want it to just be blank until July data is entered.

Comment: `=IF(yourformula=0,"",yourformula)`. Can be simplified with `LET` if your version of Excel supports it.